# SCSS Themes - Applying Namespace to Mapping

Tags: css, sass

I am using the following code to create two themes for a website - the default and a client - with the likelihood I would add more themes in the future.

However, I can't seem to get around the fact that using @each and mapping is incredibly frustrating, as not only do I need to basically duplicate all of my code, I have to remember to add every variable to every theme every time I make one. This seems like it would lead to disaster in the future, as there could potentially be a huge amount of variables.

Is there a way to have it iterate through a list of all of the variables so there's just one list, and it adds the theme namespace to each in an each or for loop? Everything I tried, such as doing #{$theme}.variable, just led to the same error - "Error: Interpolation isn't allowed in namespaces." When I tried --#{$name}: #{$theme + "." + $name + "-base"}, this almost seemed to work except it took the whole thing as literal, producing --font-size: default.$font-size-base ... aka: not the variable --font-size: 13px.

Any thoughts would be very helpful!

```
@use './_themes/default' as default;
@use './_themes/client' as client;

$variables: (
    "default": (      
        "font-color": default.$font-color-base,
        "font-family": default.$font-family-base,
        "font-size": default.$font-size-base,
    ),
    "client": (       
        "font-color": client.$font-color-base,
        "font-family": client.$font-family-base,
        "font-size": client.$font-size-base,
    )    
);

@each $theme, $properties in $variables {
    body.#{$theme} {
        @each $name, $property in $properties {
            --#{$name}: #{$property};
        }
    }
}
```